Modernizing My Use Of reposurgeon for SVN-to-git Conversion
I have a large number of SVN repos I need to convert to git.  I've been using version 4.4 of reposurgeon but want to upgrade to the latest version, 5.1.  The docs describe two changes that break what I've been doing to handle my non-flat repo structure, summarized below.
trunk/
tags/
    1.1/
        tag1/
        tag2/
    1.2/
        tag1/
        tag2/
        tag3/
branches/
    experiment/
    1.1/
        feature1/
        feature2/
        feature3/
    1.2/
        feature4/
        feature5/
prod/
    tag1/
    tag2/

I've been able to convert this layout using commands branchify and branchmap.  Both of those are now obsolete, and I need to somehow replace them.  They looked like this.
branchify          \
    trunk          \
    tags/1.1/*     \
    tags/1.2/*     \
    branches/*     \
    branches/1.1/* \
    branches/1.2/* \
    prod/*

branchmap                                     \
    :trunk:heads/master:                      \
    :tags/1.1/tag1:tags/1.1/tag1              \
    :tags/1.1/tag2:tags/1.1/tag2              \
    :tags/1.2/tag1:tags/1.2/tag1              \
    :tags/1.2/tag2:tags/1.2/tag2              \
    :tags/1.2/tag3:tags/1.2/tag3              \
    :branches/experiment:heads/experiment     \
    :branches/1.1/feature1:heads/1.1/feature1 \
    :branches/1.1/feature2:heads/1.1/feature2 \
    :branches/1.1/feature3:heads/1.1/feature3 \
    :branches/1.2/feature4:heads/1.2/feature4 \
    :branches/1.2/feature5:heads/1.2/feature5 \
    :prod/tag1:tags/prod/tag1                 \
    :prod/tag2:tags/prod/tag2

The earlier link says branchify should now be done using repocutter, and branchmap should now be done using branch renames.  I haven't been able to figure out what either of those means.  Can someone provide examples of them in terms of the layout I give above?
